# How to get PHP to execute a function only following successful completion of a download?

Tags: php, download

I have the feeling this should be quite basic, but I've failed to find a solution anywhere.

I'm working on an application that sends out an email to admins when a file is downloaded. Currently the email is sent out when a download begins, but I need to change this so that it only sends when the download is completed.

I suspect something like PHP's [register_shutdown_function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) might be what I need, but [according to the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php#refsect1-function.register-shutdown-function-changelog) shutdown functions are now called before the request is completed. Which leaves me a bit stumped.

For what it's worth, the function that currently handles downloads outputs them like this:

```
readfile($path);
exit;
```

The site in question is pretty large and complicated, so ideally I'd like to make as little change to the current code as possible. Any advice on how to solve this problem would be very much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: For clarification, are you trying to run PHP after you have confirmed the download has been received by the client, or are you trying to run it after the script has stopped sending data?

Comment: Well, actually this is one thing I'm not clear about: when the script has stopped sending data, does that mean the data has all been received? Or does it just sent quickly to a cache on the web server, and then downloaded slowly from there? 

Basically, any way of postponing the email until the download is complete would be great, other than - unless there's no possible alternative! - methods involving AJAX (since the downloads are large, we don't really want users to have to wait on a "downloading" page while the file downloads).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
readfile($path);
mail('admin@example.com', 'Download completed', 'download be done, mon');
exit();
```

The readfile call will block the script until the file's been loaded and output to the webserver. Note that there is no way for a PHP script to detect if the client has actually successfully downloaded the file. The file itself will be cached partially by the webserver, and PHP's involvement ends when the webserver's cache absorbs the entire file. That means the user can abort the download (or a network glitch kills it), yet you'll still get notified that a download was completed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. So, just to be clear, are you saying there's basically no way to know for sure whether a download was completed or not? It's just that the files I'm dealing with are pretty large here (300MB+), so I'm guessing PHP could pass them to the webserver much faster than the webserver will pass them on to the client. Having said that, I don't know what the process between PHP opening a file and the client receiving it is. Will PHP's involvement end as soon as it's opened the file, or when it's passed most of the file to the client (which would still be better than nothing)?

Comment: PHP's involvement with the file will end once the last byte of the file's been sent to the webserver. readfile() boils down to `echo file_get_contents('/path/to/file');` The webserver may choose to pass on the raw bytes from PHP only as fast as the client is able to download them, or it may slurp the whole file into a buffer somewhere (making it look like a VERY fast download to php). You just can't tell which will happen.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That makes things a lot clearer. I have full control over Apache's configuration (this site is on its own dedicated server), so is there anything I can do there to force the former behaviour (pass on the raw bytes slowly, and keep PHP waiting) rather than the latter (slurp)?

Comment: You could try messing with `SendBufferSize`, but you'd be better make that a per-file override, as reducing buffer sizes globally will kill performance.

Comment: Ok, great. Just to clarify: am I correct in thinking that PHP's readfile is not going to finish executing until the client has downloaded (Filesize - SendBufferSize) bytes? So that if the webserver's buffer size is, say, 4MB, then for, say, a 300MB file, readfile will only finish executing when 296MB have actually been downloaded? (Would I be right in thinking that the buffer is likely to be < 16MB...?) If so, I think we can safely consider that a complete download. (Even sending on 50% of a complete download is better than sending at the moment download starts...)

Comment: Not sure, actually. You could so some simple timing tests. microtime calls before/after the readfile call and see how long it takes. You know how fast your link to the server is, so should be a simple matter to see if it's taking as long as the download, or completes in some shorter period.

Comment: Good idea. I'll try that this afternoon. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

`readfile()` returns the number of bytes read or `false` if there was an error.

```
$ret = readfile($path);
if($ret && $ret != 0) {
    // send e-mail
}
exit();
```